# Add style in php variable

Tags: php, html, css

I have used the simple php pagination, but now i have to add some style on my pagination. but i dont know how to add the css style in php variable. 
Here is my code:

```
   for($number=1;$number<=$messageCount;$number++)
                        {
                            echo '<a href="?page=' .$number. '">' .$number. ' &nbsp;</a>'; 

                        }
                        //echo "<br> Current Page: $page";
```

I want to add the style to $number variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell us what you've tried so far? From what I gather you're asking for a style to be added to your `$number`?

**PHP**

```
echo '<a href="?page=' .$number. '"><span class="cssClassName">' .$number. '</span></a>';
```

---

**CSS**

```
<style>
    span.cssClassName {
         /* Add your styling here */
         margin: 0 10px 0 0; /* Gets rid of the use of &nbsp; to space them out */
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it works, i already did that, btw thanks for your response !!